# Azure DataCacheClient failing to respond from time to time

Tags: caching, azure, cloud

I am experiencing a problem with azure caching. My website is a very simple website which does not use any sessions, but azure applications must have at least 1 DataCacheClient set.

The website works perfectly, there is no problem when I browse the site BUT, I have included an email notification service within the Application_error of the global ofthe site to know if users are experiencing any errors when using the site.

As soon as I included the email error sending code, my mailbox started recieving the same error which includes:

### Error Message:ErrorCode:SubStatus:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.)

Now I know that this can occur when the connection to azure services is lost, but why is it happening constantly? How can we fix it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not utilizing sessions why are you connecting to Azure cache?  You do not need to instrument Azure AppFabric cache connection in the web.config, unless you have a particular need for it.

How many instances are you running on, how big is your azure cache account and is everyone of your users receiving the error or only intermittently? If the latter, is it after a some period of inactivity on the site that folks get errors?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. We are currently working on 2 x s-small instances, 128mb cache (standard). I dont think that users are experiencing the error when visiting the site, it never happened to me, but still I receive the cache connection lost error. I know that If im not using sessions, I dont need app fabric, but it shouldnt be throwing an error! I need to know WHY its doing it, and I know there are many developers experiencing this problem. Microsoft has better come up a solution.

Comment: Are you stil using AppFabric? If you want to use cache, please use the new caching feature. You can refer to http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/ for a tutorial. If you don't need cache, you can remove all the things that are related to AppFabric cache.

Comment: @KevinVella There could be a number of reasons.. it could be due to throttling (4 connections per hour per account are allowed on your account size, but if you uploaded new app to staging slot that's 4 connections, and if you disconnected/reconnected within an hour - that's a new connection, etc)... you may have wrong connection to azure cache specified.. and it could also be an issue with the actual cache server, but that is unlikely to happen on a frequent basis